# Native Date Picker in Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I used Datepicker plugin for getting Calendar in HTML. But my boss ordered me not to  t use any jquery plugins for date picker. He is saying that I must use native code only for date picker. It should work without Javascript also.

Is it possible to create native calendar in html ?

I know html5 supports native date picker; but that is not supported by all browsers.

Can i get native date picker as following style..?

[image]

Comment: A native non-HTML5 date picker without using Javascript? Sure. It's called a textbox.

Answer (score 3):

"Native" and "without JavaScript" is where this idea will not work on older browsers. You could always create an HTML5 datepicker, and non-supportive browsers will fallback to a plain textbox. You could instruct the user to enter a date in MM/DD/YYYY format, and have this format applied by the datepicker, or by hand if the datepicker is unavailable.

This page offers some advice on the HTML5 datepicker: http://html5tutorial.info/html5-date.php

**Edit:** Alternatively, you could just create three dropdown menus and have the user select the month, day, and year. (Of course without JS in this case, you couldn't have the number of days in a month change with the user's choice, but you could always validate their input on the server.)

Answer (score 1):

> You could instruct the user to enter a date in MM/DD/YYYY format, [spryno724](https://stackoverflow.com/users/663604/spryno724)

This, a simple [`html5 placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#The_placeholder_attribute) (you can also style [`css placeholder`](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/)) would suffice.

```
<input type='text' placeholder='dd/mm/yyyy' name='form[datetime]' id='datetime' />
```

Comment: Good idea, however, if the browser doesn't support a datepicker, it likely won't support a placeholder value, either. Both of these were officially added as enhancements to the HTML5 specification. :(

Comment: @spryno724 thanks for answers. I need the following style for native Date Picker.

Answer (score 0):

why not make the jquery datepicker a fallback?

pseudocode:

```
if (! input.supports('date'))
    $(input).datepicker();
```

this way, you get a datepicker if your browser does not support the native one. That is exactly what jQuery's original 'unobtrusive' idea was.

Comment: "He is saying that I must use native code only for date picker. It should work without Javascript also." He mentioned this in the question.

Comment: i know that, and that is why i mentioned **AS A FALLBACK**. Since he also mentioned 'it should work without javascript **also**' and '... but that is not supported by all browsers'. I know developers like to fix everything with jQuery so i can understand his boss asking to fix it without it. But i also think his boss rather has a fallback to not block out 30% of the internet.

Comment: I suppose... I just figured the OP meant a datepicker of some sort should work without JS and browser support.

Answer (score -2):

Look at this simple Code. 
You need to add 2 **js** files and 1 **css** file from net.. Don't worry,It is simple

Here it is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Date</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
    <input type="text" id="dob" name="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"/>
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     var date_input=$('input[name="date"]'); 
     var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
     date_input.datepicker({
      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
      container: container,
      todayHighlight: true,
      autoclose: true,
     })
    })
   </script>
 </body>
</html>
```